# PHP how to foreach atts to list item

Tags: php, foreach

i have array

```
$id = $atts['home_blog_id'];
$slug = str_replace( array('post:','post'), array('',''), $id);
```

if echo `$id` have array: `post:du-an` and `post:tin-tuc`

if echo `$slug` have array: `du-an` and `tin-tuc`

how to foreach `$slug` to list item as

```
<li>du-an</li>
<li>tin-tuc</li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear question

Comment: @Andreas  i have array $slug item `du-an` and `tin-tuc`. but i can't foreach $slug. any idea for help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explode the items to an array the either foreach as you say or use implode.

```
$atts['home_blog_id'] ="post:du-an,post:tin-tuc";

$id = $atts['home_blog_id'];
$slug = str_replace( array('post:','post'), array('',''), $id);

echo "<li>" . implode("</li><li>", explode(",", $slug)) . "</li>";
//<li>du-an</li><li>tin-tuc</li>
```

https://3v4l.org/4j5OK

As Nigel requsted, a foreach version.

```
foreach(explode(",", $slug) as $val){
    echo "<li>" . $val . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Great answer. @Andreas Thanks you so much!